# Alinhamento de DIVs

Tags: html, css

Tenho 3 Div, e gostaria que ficassem dispostas da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A **Div1** é a div que "segura" as outras duas. Gostaria que a **DIV2** ficasse por cima da **DIV1** ,sobrepondo o texto. E que a **DIV3** ficasse no rodapé se comportando de acordo com o tamanho da **DIV2** e da **DIV1**, por exemplo: a **div1** teria um certo "min-height" e caso o texto fosse maior que esse "min-height" ela se adequaria normalmente com o tamanho do paragrafo

, sempre se ajustando de forma automática.

Comment: Utilizando ou não Bootstrap?

Comment: coloquei a biblioteca no header, mas sou iniciante em css, não uso muitos recursos...

Comment: E então, conseguiu?

Answer (score 1):

Se você declarar no html

```
<div id='div1'>
   <div id='div2'>
     'coisas aqui'
   </div>

   <div id='div3'>
     'coisas aqui'
   </div>
</div>
```

Naturalmente você terá os divs dispostos da forma que você colocou ali em cima: os divs naturalmente ficam nesse formato retangular, se extendendo de um extremo da tela até o outro, e ficam um em cima do outro.

Agora, se quiser colocar uma altura mínima para o #div1, digamos, de 300px, você deve colocar isso no seu css:

```
#div1 {
   min-height:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para o div 3 ficar sempre abaixo do div 1, como um rodapé, você pode coloca-lo fora e depois do div 1 - assim ele ficará logo abaixo dele.

Para o div 2 ficar "por cima" do div 1, você precisaria definir `position: relative` para o div 1 e `position: absolute` para o div 2, definindo onde exatamente o div 2 ficaria através das propriedades: top, left, bottom e/ou right. - No caso do seu exemplo, `bottom: 0; left: 0;`

```
<div id="div1" style="position: relative;">
   <div id="div2" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;"></div>
</div>
<div id="div3">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Todas as outras resposta deram maneiras muito boas de como você pode fazer isso, mas aqui vai um exemplo funcional com algumas considerações a mais.

Primeiramente, seu fiz um *reset* com um `box-sizing: border-box;`, seu uso é um tanto quanto opcional, entretanto, caso você deseje saber mais sobre essa propriedade, você pode dar uma olhada [**nesse artigo**](http://sergiolopes.org/css-box-sizing-border-box/). Ele faria com que as determinações de tamanhos dos elementos, já levassem em consideração por si só margens, espaçamentos, bordas, entre outras coisas.

Ficaria assim:

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Criei uma `div` com a `class="container"` que irá englobar todas as outras `div`. Ela terá o seguinte style:

```
.container {
  height: auto; 
  width: 400px; /* Mude de acordo com o desejado */
  background: #000;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Nela, basta mudar o seu `width`, e todo o resto se adequará.

A `div#div1` este style:

```
#div1 {
  height: auto !important;
  background: #000;
  min-height: 200px;
  position: relative !important;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #0090ff;
  padding: 10px; /* Margem interna para o texto */
  padding-bottom: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 5px; /* Espaçamento entre o rodapé e o texto*/
}
```

O `padding-bottom` é para caso queira que a `#div2` não fica sobre o texto. O `height: auto` fará com que a `#div1` tenha uma altura relativa ao tamanho do texto, entretanto o `min-height` cuidará para que essa altura não seja menor que 200px (ou o valor que você deseja).

Já a `div#div2` este style:

```
#div2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #0090ff;
  position: absolute !important;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
}
```

Graças ao `bottom: 0` e `left: 0` ela ficará presa ao canto inferior esquerdo da `div#div1`.

Por último a `#div3`:

```
#div3 {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100%;
   background: #cf0027;
}
```

Esta irá se deslocar de acordo com o tamanho da `#div1`. E a `width: 100%` fará com que ela tenha o tamanho da `div.container`.

### Código completo

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  height: auto;
  width: 400px;
  background: #000;
  padding: 5px;
}

#div1 {
  height: auto;
  background: #000;
  min-height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #0090ff;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#div2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #0090ff;
}

#div3 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #cf0027;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="div1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin sed efficitur arcu, sed varius eros. Sed gravida dapibus est, ut pretium tortor dapibus id. Praesent ultrices a urna sit amet pellentesque. In at rhoncus justo. Pellentesque pellentesque a
    est quis viverra. Donec vel suscipit magna, ac pharetra augue. Vivamus magna nunc, efficitur sit amet laoreet et, porttitor eu nulla.
    <div id="div2"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="div3">
  </div>
</div>
```

### [**Exemplo - JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/A8zLY/3304/)